# Adding <style> makes PyCharm stop autocomplete css

Tags: css, django, intellij-idea, autocomplete, pycharm

I have a problem with `PyCharm` autocomplete in my Django project. I've added a `<style> ... </style>` tag into the `head` of the page. When I did this, `PyCharm` stopped autocompleting css in this file - for example `col-lg...` from Bootstrap etc.

If I comment the tag or move it at the bottom of a `bootstrap.css`, autocomplete works correctly.

Is there a reason for that or it is a bug?

This is the head:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head %}
    <script src="{% static "js/scripts/newOrder.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "chosen_v1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/scripts/newOrder.js" %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static "chosen_v1.6.2/chosen.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "popselect/css/jquery.popSelect.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static "popselect/jquery.popSelect.min.js" %}"></script>

    <style> {# THIS IS THE TAG #}
        /* required to avoid jumping */
        .scrollfollowwrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 350px;

        }

        .scrollfollow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;

        }

        .scrollfollow.fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 12%;
            width: 332px;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_target_languages").popSelect({
                showTitle: false,
                placeholderText: 'Click to Add More',
                position: "bottom",
                width: 500
            });
        })
    </script>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }

    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var top = $('.scrollfollow').offset().top - parseFloat($('.scrollfollow').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0)) - 75;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                // what the y position of the scroll is
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                // whether that's below the form
                if (y >= top) {
                    // if so, ad the fixed class
                    $('.scrollfollow').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    // otherwise remove it
                    $('.scrollfollow').removeClass('fixed');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
.... Body.. ...
```

Comment: Have you added this to JetBrains issue tracker?